# How to create a trigger to allow an insert only if what is being inserted is not in a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Ok, I searched for the better part of 2 hours earlier today and was unable to find an answer to my question. So I will attempt to see if you all can help me out.

So what I want to do is create a trigger that on insert into table A will check to see if what is being inserted is in table B, if it is then do NOT insert it into any tables, just ignore the insert, otherwise continue inserting into table A.

For example, [actually very similar to my problem just different names etc]

Say I have Table A and Table B. Table B consists of say "Name" and "Address". Table A contains "Name", "Address", "favorite color", and about 3-4 more misc columns.

I want to insert "Sue", "PO Box 1 Lunar Avenue", "Grey", etc into table A. But low-and-behold there is already a "Sue", "PO Box 1 Lunar Avenue" combination in table B, so i want to ignore that insert and continue.

Neither "Name" or "Address" is a key of any sort, other than there is a constraint on the table that will not allow any "Name" and "Address" combination to be a duplicate.

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 for a reference point.

Thank you ahead of time for your answers! ^^

Comment: I have some quibbles with that schema design, but whatever.  Do you _need_ to do this as a trigger?  It's possible to 'ignore' the writes by crafting `INSERT` statements with `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clauses that reference the other table.

Comment: Is the situation symmetrical (block insert to B if value exists in A)? If not, what should happen if a value is inserted in B that already exists in A?

Comment: @X-Zero: Would be a great point if all variations of `INSERT` accepted a `WHERE` clause. (`INSERT ... VALUES` doesn't, neither does `INSERT ... EXEC`.)

Comment: @X-Zero It would be possibly to make the insert do what I am wanting, but I would much rather it be a trigger so it is on the database end instead of having a query do it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever No inserting into table B will ever happen as this is a very specific use-case, and If an insert into table B would happen, it could not be anything that would be in A just because of the nature of the information. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
CREATE TRIGGER T_TableA_I
ON TableA
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
     INSERT INTO TableA (Name,Address,/* Other columns */)
     SELECT i.Name,i.Address,/* Other columns from inserted */
     FROM
         inserted i
             left join
         TableB b
             on
                 i.Name = b.Name and
                 i.Address = b.Address
     WHERE
         b.Name is null --So the join was unsuccessful.
```

But I'm still concerned about whether a later insertion into TabelB needs to be dealt with.

Comment: Thanks this worked exactly like I wanted thanks! And as for the insert into table B, this is a very specific use-case so there will not be any inserts into table B so that should be alright.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [INSTEAD OF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) triggers which will allow you to take action before your INSERT occurs:

> An INSTEAD OF trigger can take actions such as:
>
> - Ignoring parts of a batch.
> - Not processing a part of a batch and logging the problem rows.
> - Taking an alternative action when an error condition is encountered.